# How to deploy nodejs to a different host via pm2?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am using `pm2` to deploy nodejs apps to production. Currently all apps are running in the same host. But I am going to put a few apps to a different hosts. I know `pm2` support deploying to multiple servers by defining host in an array such as: `"host" : ["212.83.163.1", "212.83.163.2", "212.83.163.3"],` But this approach will deploy all apps to all hosts listed in this array. How can I deploy some apps to one host and other apps to another hosts?

In addition, it would be good if `pm2` support master-slave mode. I have checked pm2 cluster but it doesn't seem to work in a cluster of hosts mode. It is more like a cluster of nodejs processes in one host.

Comment: `pm2 deploy app1` - app1 being an env entry, you can have multiple, they would just all be different..

Comment: This parameter is the name of the deployment target. How can I make the apps to be different for different target?